# Why populr.me theme dummy content not coming?

Tags: themes, less, handlebars.js

I am trying to build a theme using [populr.me](http://developers.populr.me/theming/index.html). I downloaded few themes from  [github](https://github.com/populr/themes). I ran them in localhost. These theme should fetch dummy-contents from lorem ipsum, and also should fetch images. But i see nothing while I run index.html in browser locally. I was connected to internet while running themes in localhost. What is wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just responded to your email. Sounds like your problem was resolved by updating main.less reference in index.html, and changing this:
`<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="/styles/main.less">`

to this:
`<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles/main.less">`

Please email me if you have further questions. Thanks for using Populr!

Answer (score 1):

As said [here](http://developers.populr.me/theming/index.html#building-locally),

the easiest way to test samples is to use a local web server. If you don't use a local web server, you will need to change every src and disable local web security.

Depending on your OS, it could be python, IIS, Apache, ...